# Jenkins: see which jobs share a lock

Tags: jenkins

How to find in jenkins web user interface which jobs share a common lock?

(I mean without access to jenkins `config.xml` on file system)

*Update:* for example jobs "compile", "test" and "deploy" share a lock to avoid one of them to begin while another is running.

Comment: Define "common lock". Are you using "Throttle concurrent builds" plugin?

Comment: @DracoAter: I'm not using "Throttle concurrent builds". The jobs potentially running simultaneously are different.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest "lock" is the queue of the slave,
assumming you set it to run one job at a time.

Looking at the slave, you could see the list of jobs attached to it.

Also, if "compile" triggers "test" which triggers "deploy",
then you could set it so new jobs will not start while downstream jobs are still running.